# Simply percent passing program not functioning correctly

Tags: c

My professor has asked us to build a simple program that takes in grades and shows the percent of the input grades that are passing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int score=0;
    double percentPassing = 0, sum = 0, passing = 0;


    do
    {
        printf("Enter a test score (-1 to quit):");
        scanf("%i", &score);

        if(score == -1){break;}

        if (score > 100)
        {
            printf("That is not a valid grade!");
        }
        if(score >=0  || score <= 100)
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
        if(score >= 70&&score <=100)
        {
            passing = passing + 1;

        }
        percentPassing = (passing/sum);
    }
    while (score != -1)


printf("\n Percent of grades that are passing: %.2d\n", percentPassing);
system("pause");
}
```

T̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶i̶d̶e̶n̶t̶i̶f̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶"̶P̶a̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶"̶ ̶i̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶d̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶7̶0̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶h̶i̶g̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶.̶ ̶

Thank you all for the help. I included a break operation at the beginning of the loop but it doesn't seam to have worked. That or another problem I don't understand is masking things. I find that the output I receive when ending the loop is always .5 when if I have given a single input of 70 -100.

P.S. My apologies for the bad formatting I'm still learning to use the site.

Comment: check your logic, you are not using score to calculate percentage.

Comment: Use a do while, why do you read the same input twice for the first time around? Make variables lowercase.

Comment: The first entry (outside the loop) is not processed. Entering -1 increments `Sum`. Look into if/else if/else. Check the return value of `scanf`. You don't calculate a percentage (only fraction) without `*100`. `PercentPassing` can be calculated outside the loop. You probably want whitespace/newlines in your `printf` calls.

Comment: `PercentPassing` is a double but printed as a float.

Comment: You also need to check the logic of your `if` statements.

Comment: I'm trying to work on applying the fixes and suggestions you have all recommended and have updated the original post with what I have managed so for. Still haven't figured out how to prevent the -1 from effecting sum. The new do while format of the code has also caused my final printf statement to gives a warning about percentPassing being set but unused even though it works when the program is run.

Comment: @HCepero `%lf` is the format specifier for a double.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(score >=0  || score <= 100)
```

Every number is either greater than or equal to zero or less than or equal to 100. There is no number that is excluded by this test.

To prevent the -1 from counting, you can add `if (score == -1) break;` before the other `if` tests. Also, you probably don't want a score of 120 to cause `passing` to be incremented.